# How to make a smooth moving Audio-Slider in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, audio, xamarin.forms, task

How can one make a smooth moving audio player in Xamarin.Forms? Thats what i tried:

- Using an MediaPlayer to play Audio-Files. Media-Player is used within
  a Service called "AudioPlayer".
- The property "AudioPosition" is bound to the value of the slider.
- There is a cancellation token used to cancel the playing.

Code looks like:

```
  await Task.Run(
            () =>
                {
                    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        this.AudioPosition = this.audioPlayer.CurrentPosition;
                    }
                },
            ct);
```

This works great if i play an audio file **once**. However, if i try to replay the file, a few times, the UI gets blocked more and more. Seems like the Task.Run() always creates a new task and doesn't "dispose" the older ones..?

I also tried to update the values in the `Device.InvokeOnMainThread()` if if i use that, the Slider won't get updated at all.

How can i update the audio slider while the file is playing in a smooth way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Timer instead of a Task with a while loop?

I assume your app is the only one controlling playback - so you could handle the timer in your playback pause / stop event handlers / commands.

The amount of code you are providing isn't enough to give more advanced suggestions.

Comment: hi there, thanks for your answer. I tried to use a Device.StartTimer and update the slider value each milisecond, but for short audiofiles (0 - 10 seconds) the timer seems not to move smoothly..

Comment: The Timer frequency should be set in relation to the file duration - somehow. For a 1 second track a 1 millisecond frequency might be good (MAYBE the slider can actually display 1000 steps). But probably it won't be a an appropriate value for anything else (the slider possibly won't even represent each change)
Find a good factor and apply that to every duration (e.g. duration * 0.005)